# Why am I losing the signal when I attach this RF amp circuit and how can I correct it?

Tags: amplifier, rf, radio, tuner

I am trying to follow this circuit diagram:

[image]

Taken from (http://www.techlib.com/electronics/crystal.html)

Using two oscilloscopes I am watching the signal on the tuner circuit and the voltage created by the amplifier. First, before connecting the RF amp circuit, I adjust the tuner to ensure I am getting a good signal, then when I connect the positive terminal from the capacitor to the tuner circuit, the amplified signal does not appear to be modulating--I'm pretty sure it's not the proper signal.

My configuration is very slightly different:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnFOI6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I suspect that the RF amp circuit is affecting my tuning, but I don't know why and I don't know how to fix or compensate for this.

Comment: Your configuration is not "slightly" different, it is completely different. Why not copy the schematic?

Comment: @KevinWhite I've updated the diagram to show what I've done. I'm not sure how different it is. I thought it would be nearly the same since I'm still using a tank circuit

Comment: The design you have there will not work very well as you have the amplifier directly across the tuning element (C1).  The original circuit was designed that way for a reason; to reduce the loading on the tuned circuit by the amplifier or detector.  Why not implement as the original design? Do you have a specific objective for implementing it like you are?

Comment: The way I have it implemented, the inductor in the tuner circuit acts as a transformer; the signal from the antenna runs through the first few coils and then straight to ground. This way I get a better signal, (which was my issue before). However, I am really curious how this is affecting my tuned circuit, this is the answer I am looking for. I thought the inductor and capacitor were in parallel so the impedance is calculated as such, but I don't know how the amp circuit is affecting it.

Comment: But you need a step down from the resonant circuit to the amplifier.  The amplifier should connect to a "a few turns" on the inductor, while the tuning capacitor connects to many turns. This is the depiction into efforts schematic.  A BJT amplifier will have a fairly low input impedance of a few kilohms so you need to tap down to the input to match the resonant circuit which will have an impedance of 10's or hundreds of kilohms.  Also your schematic has other errors.

Comment: Why should I use a step down? My original signal was 5mv without the step up action. Of course, I have a lot to learn. I'm confused as to how I can do impedance matching since my tuner circuit has variable impedance. Actually, techlib is the site you recommended to me from one of my other questions. Well, could you point out my other mistakes? I would really like to improve.

Comment: You have C4 directly connected to the power supply. The power supply directly connected to the diode. C4 should connect to the diode and R4 BUT not to the power supply. R4 should be 1k, not 100 ohm.  The PSU should be 9v. Why are you modifying the circuit given on techlib?

Comment: The only thing I modified was the tuner circuit and it was to get a little more voltage. I thought everything else was the same (I mistakenly left the default 100 ohms in the diagram). OH! You're right, I don't have a decoupling capacitor before the diode. I just tried to copy the diagram given exactly as is and assumed the disconnected wires were there to separate the abstract components (tuner, amp, demodulator). I should definitely add a capacitor there. OOH!!! I SEE MY MISTAKE! That's not a node. I've learned to use the little jump things for when wires cross but don't connect.

Comment: I'm such a noobie. Thanks for pointing this out to me. It answers my original question. If you would copy and paste it into an answer I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RF "amp" is loading the tuned circuit. When the gain pot is at Rmin you have a prospective voltage gain of maybe 100 but the input impedance could be only 500 ohm. So the mismatch is robbing your gain. When the gain pot is at Rmax, Zin goes up but gain is less than 2 anyway. This could be fixed by using a JFET like MPF102 or an emitter follower or tapping down the coil closer to ground.

Comment: I have further analyzed the circuit and I believe what you're suggesting is not the correct answer. The reason I think so is that after attaching the RF amp circuit, I must adjust my variable inductor or capacitor to get the signal back.

Comment: Hold on, you might be right and it's just that I am not understanding your answer. Kevin White also mentioned the amp circuit loading my tuned circuit. Please excuse me, I am very new to circuit design and am only familiar with analyzing DC circuits. I need an answer good enough for a "noob" like me.